# Adding two number using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I am adding two number using JS function, when I put the values 1st time for example 3 + 4 my output come as "Your answer is 7" till here it's fine. However without refreshing when I put the different values 10 + 10 then my output become  **"Your answer is 7 10"** **it does not replace 7 instead it get added to that paragraph.** what I need to change in code so I can get one value answer every time.

Many thanks in advance,
Dhanajay

```
<p> Add two number  </p>

<label for="value1">Enter Number 1</label>
<input type="text" id="value1" />
<br />
<br />

<label for="value2">Enter Number 2</label>
<input type="text" id="value2" />
<br />
<br />
<button id="calculate" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
<p id="answer">Your answer is </p>



<script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction() {
        var y = document.getElementById("value1").value;
        var z = document.getElementById("value2").value;
        var x = +y + +z;

        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML + " " + x;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Do you understand what the last line of `myFunction()` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use another element to hold the answer like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var y = document.getElementById("value1").value;
  var z = document.getElementById("value2").value;
  var x = +y + +z;

  document.getElementById("output").innerText = x;
}
```

```html
<p>Add two number</p>

<label for="value1">Enter Number 1</label>
<input type="text" id="value1" />
<br/>
<br/>

<label for="value2">Enter Number 2</label>
<input type="text" id="value2" />
<br/>
<br/>
<button id="calculate" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
<p id="answer">Your answer is <span id="output"></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<p> Add two number  </p>

<label for="value1">Enter Number 1</label>
<input type="text" id="value1" />
<br />
<br />

<label for="value2">Enter Number 2</label>
<input type="text" id="value2" />
<br />
<br />
<button id="calculate" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
<p id="answer">Your answer is </p>



<script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction() {
        var y = document.getElementById("value1").value;
        var z = document.getElementById("value2").value;
        var x = (+y + +z);

        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML =  x;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will be useful

```
function myFunction() {
     var y=null;
     var z=null;
         y = document.getElementById("value1").value;
         z = document.getElementById("value2").value;
        var x = parseInt(y) + parseInt(z);

        document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = x;
    }
```

HTML

```
<p> Add two number  </p>

<label for="value1">Enter Number 1</label>
<input type="text" id="value1" />
<br />
<br />

<label for="value2">Enter Number 2</label>
<input type="text" id="value2" />
<br />
<br />
<button id="calculate" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
<p>Your answer is </p> <span id='ans'></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML + " " + x;
```

to this:

```
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = x;
```

Comment: Hi after changing it to document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = x; my output is only showing the calculated number. What I exactly want that it also show the paragraph text "your answer is x" (where x is the calculated number). I figured it out that changing **<p id="answer">Your answer is </p>** to **<p>Your answer is <span id="answer"></span> </p>** and then putting your suggested code worked for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your last line says this

```
 document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML + " " + x;
```

It is *appending* the result to the field.

Change it to simply be

```
 document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = x;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the value in answer to int and then add x to accumulate your answer plus the new number:

```
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML) + x;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var x=0;
function myFunction() {
        var y = document.getElementById("value1").value;
        var z = document.getElementById("value2").value;
         x += parseInt(y) + parseInt(z);
console.log(x);
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML + " " + x;
    }
```

> [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/Hussy/szkeojqp/)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML + " " + x;
```

with this

```
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = " Your answer is " + x;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to purge the variables after calculation. Or else you're only appending the current definition

```
...
var x = +y + +z;    
delete y;
delete z;
```